# How to write PHP condition for Next & Previous post?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I don't know how to write if condition statement in this situation? Need some assistance. I want to completely hide a div if they don't have any next or previous posts available to show? And cover the remaining space with another available div. Hope it makes sense. Please see my final code below.

```
<div id="post-navigation">
    
    <?php
        $prev_post = get_previous_post(); 
        $prev_id = $prev_post->ID ;
        $prev_permalink = get_permalink( $prev_id );
        $prev_thumbnail =  get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $prev_id );
        $prev_image_alt = get_post_meta($prev_thumbnail, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); 
        $next_post = get_next_post();
        $next_id = $next_post->ID ;
        $next_permalink = get_permalink($next_id);
        $next_thumbnail =  get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $next_id );
        $next_image_alt = get_post_meta($next_thumbnail, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    ?>
    

    <article class="pexel-previous-post-data has-post-thumbnail pexel-box">
        <div class="pexel-nextPrev-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php echo $prev_permalink; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $prev_thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $prev_image_alt; ?>" width="200" height="200">
            </a>    
        </div>
        <header class="pexel-previous-post-text">
             <div class="entry-meta before-title prev-next-pill">
                 <span><?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Previous', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?> 
                 </span>
             </div>  
            <h5 class="pxl_head--h5 pxl_heading_anim_underline"><a href="<?php echo $prev_permalink; ?>"><?php echo $prev_post->post_title; $short_title; ?></a></h5>
        </header>
    </article>

    <article class="pexel-next-post-data has-post-thumbnail pexel-box">
        <div class="pexel-nextPrev-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php echo $next_permalink; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $next_thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $next_image_alt; ?>" width="200" height="200">
            </a>    
        </div>
        <header class="pexel-next-post-text">
             <div class="entry-meta before-title next-next-pill">
                 <span><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?> 
                 </span>
             </div>  
            <h5 class="pxl_head--h5 pxl_heading_anim_underline"><a href="<?php echo $next_permalink; ?>"><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a></h5>
        </header>
    </article>      

</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the `if` statement?

Comment: Please read the question...i want to add if statement..in next & previous div

Comment: I read your question. I mean, try to put the if statement somewhere and see what happens. If you run into trouble, then come back here and you'll definitely get help.

Comment: I tried several times to add this but it is not working at all... so that's why I'm looking for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to completely hide the `post-navigation` div, if there is no next post.  You should be able to figure out the rest of what you want from this example.

This uses the `is_a` function, since the `get_next_post` either returns an empty string, null, or a `post object` so if you check if the value is a `WP_POST` object you can show or hide your div as you want.  Always remember to escape your output also.

```php
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();
// check to see if $next_post is something or nothing.
if ( is_a( $next_post, 'WP_POST' ) ) :
    $next_id        = $next_post->ID;
    $next_permalink = get_permalink( $next_id );
    $next_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $next_id );
    $next_image_alt = get_post_meta( $next_thumbnail, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
?>
<div id="post-navigation">
    <article class="pexel-next-post-data has-post-thumbnail pexel-box">
        <div class="pexel-nextPrev-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $next_permalink ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $next_thumbnail ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $next_image_alt ); ?>" width="200" height="200">
            </a>
        </div>
        <header class="pexel-next-post-text">
            <div class="entry-meta before-title next-next-pill">
                <span><?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></span>
            </div>
            <h5 class="pxl_head--h5 pxl_heading_anim_underline">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $next_permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr( $next_post->post_title ); ?></a>
            </h5>
        </header>
    </article>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```